# C# cast to interface with List and GroupBy

Tags: c#, casting, group-by, interface, linq-to-objects

I'm a bit stumped about how to perform the necessary cast in the following:

```
public IList<IMyClass> Foo()
{
    IList<IMyClass> foo = SomeQuery(); 

    var result = foo.GroupBy(x => x.bar).Select(x => new MyClass()).ToList();

    // So now I have a List<MyClass> which needs casting as IList<IMyClass>

    return result;
}
```

using an explicit cast fails at run time. The error message isn't helpful but I'm guessing it maybe something to do with the GroupBy as I wouldn't normally expect to have any problem with something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `GroupBy` - it's because `IList<T>` is invariant. If you *could* cast a `List<MyClass>` to `IList<IMyClass>` then the caller could then add an instance of a type which implemented `IMyClass` but *wasn't* a `MyClass`. (I usually think of this in terms of real world objects: a bunch of bananas isn't a fruit bowl: you can add an apple to a fruit bowl, but not to a bunch of bananas.)

The simplest way would be to manually specify the type in the Select clause:

```
public IList<IMyClass> Foo()
{
    IList<IMyClass> foo = SomeQuery(); 

    var result = foo.GroupBy(x => x.bar)
        .Select<IGrouping<IMyClass, Bar>>, IMyClass>(x => new MyClass())
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

This means `result` will actually be a `List<IMyClass>`. I don't know the type of item within `foo` which makes it tricky to give it in more detail - given your comment, I'll assume that *that's* `IMyClass`, and that x.bar is of type `Bar`.

Another alternative (which would be more useful if you wanted to use a query expression for the group/select part) would be to use `Cast`:

```
public IList<IMyClass> Foo()
{
    IList<IMyClass> foo = SomeQuery(); 

    var result = foo.GroupBy(x => x.bar)
                    .Select(x => new MyClass())
                    .Cast<IMyClass>()
                    .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Or perform the cast within the Select lambda expression itself:

```
public IList<IMyClass> Foo()
{
    IList<IMyClass> foo = SomeQuery(); 

    var result = foo.GroupBy(x => x.bar)
                    .Select(x => (IMyClass) new MyClass())
                    .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: Apologies for the `Select` failure. It's somewhat annoying that you have to specify both the source and the result, but there's no easy way of fixing that :( Given the ugliness involved, you may well be best off with `Cast`.

Comment: ah, never used the generic Select clause... see. lerned something new. thanks.

Comment: @cRichter: `Enumerable.Select` is always a generic method - it's just that *usually* you let the compiler infer the type argument.

Comment: Hi Jon: I can't get the first example to compile. It says `Select` needs both a `TSource` and `TResult`, but when I try that I get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<IMyClass>> doesn't contain a definition for Select` error. You might want to double check this part of your answer. I've got it working with `Cast` though, thanks.

Comment: @fearofawahckplannet: Oops - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use .net 4?

then its easy.
just return an IEnumerable of IMyClass.
that supports covariance, and therefore you can cast it to base types.

otherwise. do this.

```
result.Select(i=> (IMyClass)i).ToList();
```

Comment: I would assume that the OP *wants* to return an `IList<T>` so that the caller can do list-y type things with it.

Comment: True. but... in fact. developers are the lazy kind of guys. so they are using normally the interface that is the easiest. and not that maybe would be the correct one^^